# mssql node js package not found when running azure function

Tags: node.js, sql-server, azure-functions, azure-app-service-plans, azure-functions-core-tools

I'm trying to connect SQL server inside azure function locally,
and I'm getting the following error,

```
[error] Worker was unable to load function timerTriggerWithEventHub: 'Error: Cannot find module 'mssql''
```

But I have installed mssql package in my machine,

here is my code,

```
const sql = require('mssql').Request;
module.exports = async function (context, myTimer) {
    var config = {
        user: 'sa',
        password: 'Gain@123',
        server: 'DESKTOP-J7IPQ7H', 
        database: 'RealTimeProductSales' 
    };
    sql.connect(config, function (err) {    
        if (err) console.log(err);
        // create Request object
        var request = new Request();           
        // query to the database and get the records
        request.query('select * from dbo.ProdTC', function (err, recordset) {            
            if (err) console.log(err)
            console.log(recordset)
            // send records as a response
            // res.send(recordset);

        });
    });

    // console.log('saranraj')
    // console.log(context,myTimer)
    // var timeStamp = new Date().toISOString();

    // if (myTimer.IsPastDue)
    // {
    //     context.log('JavaScript is running late!');
    // }
    // context.log('JavaScript timer trigger function ran!', timeStamp);   
    // return "{'name':'saran'}"
};
```

when I install the package i'm getting output like this

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\SivaSakthiVelan\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\SivaSakthiVelan\package.json'
npm WARN SivaSakthiVelan No description
npm WARN SivaSakthiVelan No repository field.
npm WARN SivaSakthiVelan No README data
npm WARN SivaSakthiVelan No license field.

+ mssql@5.1.0
updated 1 package and audited 11650 packages in 6.832s
found 226 vulnerabilities (42 moderate, 184 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the package.json is missing.

You can try to run the command below:

```
npm init -f
```

This command above will help you initialize a package.json (-f means force).

You can check the dependencies in your package.json.

And then run the command below:

```
npm install mssql
```

Comment: Hi @saran, may I know if this answer is helpful to your issue ?